# What concentration (M) of citric acid should I use in a titration with 0.02M LiOH?

Tags: acid-base, concentration, titration

I am using an automatic titrator that records the amount of acid/base added and the pH of the solution in the form of a graph. I am trying to titrate citric acid to capture all 3 pKas in this graph. I will be titrating 40mL of a ???M citric acid solution made up in 0.01M LiNO3 as a background electrolyte. The software's titration schedule begins by adding increments of 0.1M HNO3 until the pH reaches 2.5, then it adds increments of 0.02M LiOH until the pH reaches 10. What concentration (M) of citric acid should I use in this titration in order to capture its pKas?

Comment: We need to know how big the increments of are to answer this question.  Are they 1 mL?  0.01 mL?

Comment: The largest increment is 0.1mL. However, the titration software decreases the mL of base added as the titration reaches equivalence point. So at the beginning of the titration, the increments are 0.1mL LiOH added, but as the pH begins to increase rapidly with each addition, the increments decrease non-continuously (down to a minimum increment of 0.01mL), then after the equivalence point has passed the increments increase again. Hope this helps.